# Drag and drop item from UITableView to UITableView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview, custom-cell

I know there are number of threads available on stackoverflow regarding drag & drop between two UITableView but I am not able to work on it smoothly.

Please do not post links of that stackoverflow as a refrence here in this thread because I have already gone through that.

So....

I have created a main UIViewController under which I have added two UITableView i.e. tableView1, tableView2

Under which I have added customCell and UIView enclosed with images on that cell. Now if i will use touchesMoved delegate its not working at all for me. Instead of I have gesture recognizer like so:

```
//Custom cell for planned spend details progress bars....
- (void) customCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {

    UIView *progressView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, 2.0, 320.0, 97.0)];
    [self setProgressBars:progressView];
    progressView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [self addGestureRecognizersToView:progressView];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:progressView];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [progressView release];

}
```

setProgressBars is a method where I have added UIImageView.

Now using UIRotationGestureRecognizer I am able to drag and drop UIImageViews within single UITableView. Its not working at all If I will drag outside the premises of that UITableView.

Please help in order to resolve my problem so that I am able to drag items from one UITableView to another

Comment: Its being more than a month and no one has answered yet. Strange.

well I have completed this task by my own.

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer; but please don't just put *I fixed this on my own*.  A paragraph may be all that is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some working code: [How to copy cells between tables as the pulse app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315990/how-copy-cells-between-tables-as-the-pulse-app), but the animation is crap. If interested, we can join forces and release it as open source...

**UPDATE**: My progress so far: https://bitbucket.org/elmalabarista/dragdroptableviews