# How to copy cells between tables as the pulse app

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, ios4, drag-and-drop

I need to copy cells [between 2 table views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061693/how-move-reorder-cells-from-tableview1-to-tableview2).

I have a more-or-less working solution. However, it is not smooth, and I would love to do something similar to the [pulse app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pulse-news-reader/id371088673?mt=8) reorder feeds option...

Something special in the way that pulse works, is that the reorder animation is the same as in a normal reorder of cells, but still the cell can move between tables.

This is what I have now:

```
- (BoardColumnView *) addColumn:(NSString *)title type:(ColumnType)type{
    BoardColumnView *col = [BoardColumnView createColumn:title];

    [self.columns addObject:col];

    // Add a pinch gesture recognizer to the table view.
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* draggingRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                                    initWithTarget:self 
                                                    action:@selector(moveActionGestureRecognizerStateChanged:)
                                                   ];

    draggingRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
    draggingRecognizer.delegate = self;

    [col.tableView addGestureRecognizer:draggingRecognizer];
    [draggingRecognizer release]; 


    return col;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIGestureRecognizer Delegate/Actions

- (BOOL) gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: (UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
{
    ALog(@"Drag detected");
    return YES;
}

- (void) moveActionGestureRecognizerStateChanged: (UIGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    switch ( recognizer.state )
    {
        default:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
            // do nothing
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        {
            ALog(@"Canceled");

            [UIView beginAnimations: @"SnapBack" context: NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
            [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
            [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(finishedSnap:finished:context:)];

            CGRect f = self.dragView.frame;
            f.origin = _dragOriginCellOrigin;
            self.dragView.frame = f;

            [UIView commitAnimations];

            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        {
            // move the real cell into place
            [UIView beginAnimations: @"SnapToPlace" context: NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
            [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
            [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(finishedSnap:finished:context:)];

            CGRect r = self.dragView.frame;//[self.content rectForItemAtIndex: _emptyCellIndex];
            CGRect f = self.dragView.frame;
            f.origin.x = r.origin.x + floorf((r.size.width - f.size.width) * 0.5);
            f.origin.y = r.origin.y + floorf((r.size.height - f.size.height) * 0.5);
            NSLog( @"Gesture ended-- moving to %@", NSStringFromCGRect(f) );
            self.dragView.frame = f;

            self.dragView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            self.dragView.alpha = 1.0;

            [UIView commitAnimations];
            break;
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        {           
            ALog(@"Start move..");
            // find the cell at the current point and copy it into our main view, applying some transforms
            _lastColumn = (BoardColumnView *)[(UITableView *)recognizer.view superview];
            _targetColumn = _lastColumn;

            if (_lastIndexPath) {
                [_lastIndexPath release];
                _lastIndexPath = nil;
            }

            _lastIndexPath = [_lastColumn.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[recognizer locationInView: _lastColumn]];

            UITableViewCell *sourceCell = [_lastColumn.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_lastIndexPath];

            CGRect frame = [_lastColumn convertRect: sourceCell.frame fromView: self.content];

            self.dragView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[sourceCell screenshot]] autorelease];
            self.dragView.opaque = YES;
            self.dragView.backgroundColor = _lastColumn.backgroundColor;

            self.dragView.center = [recognizer locationInView: self.view];
            //self.dragView.cornerRadius = 8; // if you like rounded corners
            self.dragView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5, 2);
            self.dragView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
            self.dragView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

            [content addSubview: self.dragView];

            [content bringSubviewToFront:self.dragView];
            // grab some info about the origin of this cell
            _dragOriginCellOrigin = frame.origin;

            [UIView beginAnimations: @"" context: NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

            // transformation-- larger, slightly transparent
            self.dragView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( 1.2, 1.2 );
            self.dragView.alpha = 0.7;

            [UIView commitAnimations];

            /* // reload the grid underneath to get the empty cell in place
            [self.content reloadItemsAtIndices: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: index]
                              withAnimation: AQGridViewItemAnimationNone];
            */
            break;
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        {
            // update draging cell location
            self.dragView.center = [recognizer locationInView: self.view];

            //Determinar sobre que columna esta flotando..
            CGRect global;

            if (_targetColumn) {
                _targetColumn = nil;
            }
            for (BoardColumnView *col in self.columns) {
                UITableView *table = col.tableView;
                global = [table convertRect:self.dragView.frame fromView:content];

                if ([table pointInside:global.origin withEvent:nil]) {
                    ALog([NSString stringWithFormat: @"Esta sobre la tabla %@", col.column.name]);
                    _targetColumn = col;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ( !_targetColumn )
            {                
                ALog(@"Esta en zona muerta");
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void) finishedSnap: (NSString *) animationID finished: (NSNumber *) finished context: (void *) context
{       
    if (_targetColumn && _lastIndexPath) {      
        ALog(@"Moviendo a nuevo destino");

        CGRect frame = [_targetColumn convertRect: self.dragView.frame fromView: self.content];     
        NSIndexPath *destPath  = [_targetColumn.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: frame.origin];

        [UIView beginAnimations: @"" context: NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

        self.dragView.backgroundColor = _targetColumn.backgroundColor;

        //Si inserta entre tareas en destino...

        _lastColumn.totalRows -= 1;
        _targetColumn.totalRows += 1;

        [_lastColumn.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:_lastIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

        if (destPath) {         
            [_targetColumn.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:destPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
        } else {
            [_targetColumn.tableView reloadData];
        }



        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {        
        ALog(@"Cancelado el moviento, regresar a home");

        UITableViewCell * sourceCell = [_lastColumn.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_lastIndexPath];        
        if (sourceCell) {

            [UIView beginAnimations: @"Back" context: NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
            [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
            [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

            //self.dragView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            self.dragView.frame = [self.content convertRect: sourceCell.frame fromView: _lastColumn];
            //self.dragView.alpha = 0.0;

            [UIView commitAnimations];      
        }
    }
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(id)animationID finished:(BOOL)flag context:(id)context {
    // dismiss our copy of the cell
    ALog(@"Eliminando drag view");
    [self.dragView removeFromSuperview];
    self.dragView = nil;

    _lastColumn = nil;
    _targetColumn = nil;

    if (_lastIndexPath) {
        _lastIndexPath = nil;
    }   
}
```

**UPDATE:** I've created an open source project to show my progress so far:

https://bitbucket.org/elmalabarista/dragdroptableviews

Comment: I recommend you read this tutorials about similar pulse app http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1 http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2 and this is the OpenSource http://www.raywenderlich.com/downloads/HorizontalTables2.zip Enjoy!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ipad: Drag a UITableViewCell from one UITableViewController and drop it into another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506946/ipad-drag-a-uitableviewcell-from-one-uitableviewcontroller-and-drop-it-into-ano)